# Publishing in a Loop

Tags: python, autobahn, wamp-protocol

I am trying to publish something in a infinite loop. But its not working. If I try the same code without the loop it seems to work fine.

```
while True:
    print 'XYZ'
    self.publish(str(gameId), [obj], [], {}, {'acknowledge': True})
    #self.publish(str(gameId), [obj])
    time.sleep(5)
```

The above code prints 'XYZ' infinitely but I am not able to receive the publish on my client. The below code works fine and I receive the obj publish sends:

```
self.publish(str(gameId), [obj])
self.publish(str(gameId), [obj])
self.publish(str(gameId), [obj])
```

Comment: Can you explain the way in which it isn't working? Do you get an error message? Invalid output?

Comment: @BlackVegetable No I do not get any error message. If I add say print 'XYZ' it seems to print it infinitely without issue. Its just that self.publish doesn't seem to work in case of infinite loop.

Comment: Could you add the argument `acknowledge=True` to your publish call? It should raise an error or something similar, instead of the default silent failure pattern.

Comment: @BlackVegetable is this what you meant? I did not get any errors

Comment: That might be one way to pass that argument.  The typical way is `self.my_function(normal_argument1, normal_argument2, keyword_argument=value)` such as `self.publish(str(gameId), [obj], acknowledge=True)`.  That's troubling if it didn't error out. :(

Comment: See the documentation here http://autobahn.ws/python/reference/autobahn.wamp.html#autobahn.wamp.interfaces.IPublisher.publish for the pattern to get a Future return value from the `publish` call if `acknowledge=True`.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I made this change to the code                `print self.publish(str(gameId), [obj], acknowledge = True)`
And it prints None

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97881/discussion-between-blackvegetable-and-karma).